# Where to unhide a hidden part?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am implementing functionality to hide / unhide some content in my word add in. Such content may be on multiple parts of the document, and anywhere.

So i will have user insert such content to a content control. For hiding, i plan to get the ooxml of contents of the content control and persist somewhere. Then I replace the content of the control with " " or something. While unhiding, i can use the id of control to find where to insert back ooxml.

The problem is that when i hide, that "empty" content control occupies one line. Bearable, but undesirable.

I could hide the control itself too, but how would i know where in the document to insert the ooxml back?

How would you approach this?

Alternatively, can i filter out such content only when printing?

Comment: How about formatting the line height and/or font size to a very small value, as well as ensuring there's no Paragraph SpaceBefore/SpaceAfter? These setting can be stored in a ***Style**. Have one style for filled content controls, another for "hidden"; change the style when the content is written/removed. Note: You should look at Custom XML Parts for storing the ooxml. I suggest this, rather than "hiding" since Word On-line doesn't support the hidden font property, so it's not part of Office JS. *However*, if the content control were "hidden" it should still be "visible" to your code.

Comment: @CindyMeister: Yeah, that is possible. The best solution would depend on the application I guess. Luckily the docs I target have a lot of structure and so this time I am thinking about having user add a control that will not be hidden. So hidden controls can be repositioned using those unhidden controls. Downside is i will have users insert these otherwise unnecessary controls. So they will have to do a little more work.

Comment: OK, I just did a quick test, since I'm at my main machine. It is possible to format a content control and its paragraph as "hidden" (font formatting). Only caveat is that Word JS APIs don't have this because it's not supported by Word On-line. *BUT* if these are structured, prepared documents you could have a style pair (one with hidden, the other with not) defined in the document (or a template) and apply the *style* to the paragraph as required. That would be the most elegant and simplest approach - no additional work for the user.